# Linker errors when using boost serialization

Tags: c++, macos, boost, ld, boost-serialization

I am using boost serialization. I compiled with: `-L/opt/local/lib -lboost_serialization -stdlib=libc++`, but got several (ungooglable) errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl::save(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&)", referenced from:
      void boost::archive::save_access::save_primitive, std::__1::allocator > >(boost::archive::text_oarchive&, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&) in main.o
  "boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive > >::~basic_text_oprimitive()", referenced from:
      boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl::~text_oarchive_impl() in main.o
  "boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl::text_oarchive_impl(std::__1::basic_ostream >&, unsigned int)", referenced from:
      boost::archive::text_oarchive::text_oarchive(std::__1::basic_ostream >&, unsigned int) in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I am serializing an `std::vector<std::string>`:

```
boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(std::cout);
oa << tasks;
```

Is there a problem with my installation of boost?

---

The boost libraries are universal binaries containing both 32-bit and 64-bit machine code (so that's not the problem I guess):

> ```
> $ file libboost_serialization.dylib
> libboost_serialization.dylib: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
> libboost_serialization.dylib (for architecture i386): Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
> libboost_serialization.dylib (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
> ```

I installed boost using `sudo port install boost +universal` on Mac OS X 10.7.

Comment: Maybe boost was built with different compiler than what you are using? I had similar problems with macports in the past, but too long ago to remember the details.

Comment: Can you post a small example showing how you are trying to use the serialization library? I haven't used it but I'm quite confident that I can track down the issue once I have a working test case... (working as in: shows the problem).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I could reproduce the problem using the following code:

```
#include "boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp"
#include "boost/serialization/vector.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> tasks;
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(std::cout);
    oa << tasks;
}
```

This compiles and links without problems when using `g++` or `clang++` with their respective default flags and linking with `-lboost_serialization`. However, when using `clang++` with `libc++` linking fails with essentially the error messages quote (I have Boost installed at `/opt/boost`):

```
clang++ -c -stdlib=libc++ -I/opt/boost -W -Wall -ansi serialize.cpp
clang++ -o serialize.tsk -L/opt/boost/stage/lib -stdlib=libc++ serialize.o -lboost_serialization
```

Based on this I assumed that a build with -stdlib=libc++ wants to have its own Boost build and build one using based on the [Boost installation guide](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html):

```
tar jxvf ~/Downloads/boost_1_48_0.tar.bz2
cd boost_1_48_0/tools/build/v2

# change the build rules to use -stdlib=libc++:
mv tools/clang-darwin.jam tools/clang-darwin.jam.orig
sed -e 's/CONFIG_COMMAND)"/CONFIG_COMMAND)" -stdlib=libc++/' < tools/clang-darwin.jam.orig > tools/clang-darwin.jam

./boostrap.sh
sudo ./b2 install --prefix=/opt/boost-clang
cd ../../..
/opt/boost-clang/bin/b2 --build-dir=/opt/tmp toolset=clang stage
sudo /opt/boost-clang/bin/b2 --build-dir=/opt/tmp toolset=clang install --prefix=/opt/boost-clang
```

The edits I made to `clang-darwin.jam` are almost certainly not those intended but they seem to do the trick: I don't know much about "bjam" and I just tried to find an appropriate location to apply the change. Some step of the installation use `sudo` to install things into protected directories. Obviously, you can install into some other directory where you have write permissions as well. I just installed things on my machine in a way preventing me from accidentally messing it up.

However, with this installation in place I could successfully build the program:

```
/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -W -Wall -ansi -I/opt/boost-clang  -c -o serialize.o serialize.cpp
/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -L/opt/boost-clang/lib serialize.o -lboost_serialization -o serialize.tsk
```

Comment: For me, I needed `-I/opt/boost-clang` to compile. For me I'm still failing at the linking stage after following all of these steps. MacOS 10.13.6 High Sierra. Using Boost 1.69. Slight modification to the steps but mostly the same.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your boost libraries may be 32 bit.

That's a problem you wouldn't notice until you tried to use one of the few boost utils that are not header-only.

Comment: Run command "file *boost_ser*.so". It will tell you whether it is for 32 bit arch or 64 bit arch .

Comment: "libboost_serialization.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64" mmm…

Comment: @WTP What does `otool -vf libboost_serialization.dylib` display?

Comment: I'm having this problem. I'm on a 64 bit mac with a 64 bit boost install from homebrew. I got no output from the `otool` command (I had to type full path), and for `file`, I got `lib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64`